# How to check if memcached is working in SSH

Tags: memcached

I don't know a lot of things for server, but my provider sent me a message and it says to add a password to memcached.

I believe that is on the server.
How / Where can I check it? Or how to check if memcached is running in SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
watch 'php -r '"'"'$m=new Memcache;$m->connect("127.0.0.1", 11211);print_r($m->getstats());'"'"
```

Comment: Care to elaborate your answer?

Comment: I'd like to upvote this as it was a useful answer, but the previous comment is absolutely valid, it needs further explanation.